# How to get certain information out of arraylist grouped into other lists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, information-retrieval

I wrote a program, that reads multiple (similar) textfiles out of  a Folder. Im splitting the information by space and store everything in one arraylist which contains data kind of this:

```
key1=hello
key2=good
key3=1234
...
key15=repetition
key1=morning
key2=night
key3=5678
...
```

Now I'm looking for a way to get those information out of this list and somehow grouped by their keys into other lists. So im looking for a way to get a result like this:

```
keyList1 = {hello,morning}
keyList2 = {good,night}
```

and so on.

So I have to check very line for a keyword such as "key1" and split the value at the "=" and go on and on.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the datastructure that suits your (described) needs best is a MultiMap. It is like a map, but with the possibility to store more than one value for a key.

For example the implementation from the guava project.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

First, you have to iterate over the arraylist:

```
    final Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    for ( String element : arrayList ) {
        String[] splitted = element.split( "=" );
        multimap.put( splitted[0], splitted[1] );
    }
```

You get a List of values the following way:

```
    for (String key : multimap.keySet()) {
      List<String> values = multimap.get(key);
    }
```

You might want to add some sanity checks for the splitting of your Strings.

(Code is untested)

Comment: Yes great! This library was exatly what I was looking for and super easy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be looking something like this kind of grouping (assuming you have access to Java 8)

```
List<String> pairs = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"));
Map<String, List<String>> map = pairs
        .stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        arr -> arr[0],
                        LinkedHashMap::new,//to preserve order of keys
                        Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1],
                                Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println(pairs);
System.out.println("---");

System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
[key1=hello, key2=good, key3=1234, key15=repetition, key1=morning, key2=night, key3=5678]
---
{key1=[hello, morning], key2=[good, night], key3=[1234, 5678], key15=[repetition]}
```